# Как добавить класс к элементу в templateLayoutFactory, для cluster'a на карте, при клике

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Не могу понять, как добавить класс на элемент внутри конкретного кластера

```
initMap() {
  // Инициализация карты
  const map = new ymaps.Map('map', {
    center: [45.015792, 39.034979],
    zoom: 15,
    controls: []
  }),

  // Создаем элемент кластера
  createClusterIconLayout = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(
    '<div class="map__placemark">' +
    '$[properties.iconLayout]' + '<span class="map__placemark-text">5</span>' +
    '</div>');

  const clusterer = new ymaps.Clusterer({
    clusterize: true,
    hasBalloon: false,
    hasHint: false,
    clusterGroupByCoordinates: false,
    clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
    clusterIconLayout: createClusterIconLayout,
    clusterDisableClickZoom: true,
    clusterHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
    geoObjectHideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
    clusterIconShape: {
      type: 'Rectangle',
      coordinates: [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 40, 40 ] ],
    },
    iconOffset: [ -21, -21 ],
  });

  this.placeMarks.forEach((placemark, index) => {
    this.geoObjects[index] = new ymaps.Placemark(placemark, {}, {
      iconLayout: createClusterIconLayout,
      iconShape: {
        type: 'Rectangle',
        coordinates: [ [ 0, 0 ], [ 40, 40 ] ],
      },
      iconOffset: [ -21, -21 ],
    });
  });

  clusterer.add(this.geoObjects);

  map.geoObjects.add(clusterer);

  clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
    debugger;

    // В этот момент нужно как-то обратиться на именно тот кластер, который нажал и навесить класс '.map__placemark--active' только на его iconLayout
    let customCluster = document.querySelector('.map__placemark');
    if (customCluster.classList.contains('map__placemark--active')) {
      customCluster.classList.remove('map__placemark--active')
    } else {
      customCluster.classList.add('map__placemark--active');
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
clusterer.events.add('click', function (e) {
    var clustererPlacemark = e.get('target');
    var overlay = clustererPlacemark.getOverlaySync();
    var layout = overlay.getLayoutSync();
    var element = layout.getParentElement();
    doWhateverYouWant(element);
});
```

Comment: отлично! огромные благодарности, но есть еще один вопрос :) возможно в данной функции выполнить действие "для всех остальных кластеров, кроме кликнутого"?

Comment: @4e4e4i  `clusterer.getClusters()` возвращает все кластеры добавленные на карту. Имея их можно, например, `clusters.filter(cluster => cluster !== clickedCluster)` сделать.

Comment: Сlusters, cluster и clickedCluster это как получить? как я понимаю clusters = clusterer.getClusters() - то есть он возвращает объект нам, а вот дальше я чего-то не допираю... а то я уже как только не пробовал через ваш вариант, сорри за необразованность, если есть возможность поясните подробнее, пожалуйста

Comment: `clickedCluster` - тот, в который кликнули (`clusterPlacemark` из ответа).